# Parallelisation strategies for mixed FE formulations

Tags: finite-element, parallel-computing, petsc, domain-decomposition, saddlepoint

Mixed FE formulations with LBB-stable elements require two different meshes for the primary and the constraint variables, for example, displacement and pressure. With continuous approximation for the pressure field, I am finding it difficult to parallelise for distributed memory architectures.

I am interested in learning some commonly employed parallelisation strategies for such problems. I very much appreciate any useful resources on this topic.

Note that I use the PETSc library for solving the matrix system in my C++ code.

Comment: Are the meshes for both fields same but just the polynomial degree are different? For example, do you use a triangular mesh for displacement and a rectangular mesh for pressure? Is it such a case?

Comment: The mesh is the same but with different orders of polynomials for different fields, like the Taylor-Hood elements, P2/P1 and Q2/Q1.

Comment: Then there are many ways to handle it, Wolfgang Bangerth is one of the developers of deal.ii so consider his answer and advise. But I am also very fond of the way MFEM handles it (https://mfem.org/performance/)

Comment: Thank you for the link! MFEM is a great library. I will go through the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It's a misunderstanding that you need two different meshes: The proper way to see things is that you are using the same mesh, but different polynomial spaces for the two variables. For example, for the Stokes equation, you'd have quadratic polynomials for the velocity $\mathbf u$ and linear polynomials for the pressure $p$.

Appropriate parallelization strategies are then to partition the mesh among processors. This also induces a partitioning of degrees of freedom, and consequently of those rows of the matrix (and vector elements) each processor stores. It's really no different than if you had a scalar problem.

Comment: I was thinking the same but then there are inf-sup stable finite elements where the velocity mesh is simplectic and the pressure mesh is tensor-product. I wonder if it is such a case.

Comment: Thank you @Wolfgang! I agree that we don't need two different meshes. With a single mesh, one can get processor IDs for each element and node in the mesh using METIS. However, processor id colouring is available only for either displacement nodes or pressure nodes. The straightforward technique would be to use the same colouring for pressure nodes as that of displacement nodes. This is what I am currently implementing.

Comment: @ChennaK: Well, you should color *cells* and then infer the color of nodes based on that of the cells. Then you have the same partitioning for pressures and velocities.

Comment: Regarding partitioning of the matrix, in the serial version of the code, I store displacement DOFs first and then pressure DOFs, so that I have the 2x2 block matrix format. Partitoning such a matrix across processors would be cumbersome and leads to complex and inefficient communication pattern.
I guess I need to change the arrangement of the matrix such the displacement DOFs on each processor are followed immediately by pressure DOFs on the same processor.
I would like to know if there are any other efficient ways of implementing this.

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas Right, one can concoct difficult choices of elements where the two variables are discretized in completely different ways (say, a global Fourier basis for $\mathbf u$ and a piecewise polynomial basis for $p$). But I don't think the OP was asking about such cases.

Comment: @ChennaK -- whether it's cumbersome or inefficient depends on whether you want to do it all yourself. All of these things are of course already implemented in all of the major finite element packages. You need to ask yourself whether you want to spend your time re-inventing the wheel, or whether you'd much rather start with a package that already does all of these things for you, scales to 100,000s of processors, and allows you to focus on the actual equation you want to solve, rather than relatively boring infrastructure code for partitioning meshes and matrices.

Comment: Thank you @WolfgangBangerth! No matter how good and matured the existing libraries are, they all are limited in their capability in one or other aspect. I would be very much limited in my research work if I used the existing libraries. For example, if I stick to deal.ii, then I won't be able to use triangular/tetrahedral elements. FEniCS does not support hexa elements yet.
Nevertheless, I learn from the existing codes and adapt the good points from different libraries into my code. I learnt a lot from the deal.ii implementation.

Comment: @ChennaK That's your choice of course, but I'd still suggest you ask yourself what is important about the research you do. Is it that you *need* to use triangles? That you *need* to use hexahedra? Both? It's true that all of these libraries only have 90% of what you have, but you could see if maybe the remaining 10% can be added -- whereas, of course, with your own code, you're still only at 20% and will *always* only be at 20% because you can spend many years on implementing efficient parallelization strategies, adaptivity, multigrid, AMG, higher order elements, <long list to follow>.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Appreciate your suggestions very much. Having my own code gives me flexibility. I have evaluated deal.ii and FEniCS and decided against using them because of the limited support in terms of element shapes.

I hope you understand that moving my workflow to a new code base is not an easy task. I have parallelised my codes in the past, and I think I can do this quickly. I am not interested in using more 100 CPUs, and also won't be using MG and adaptivity.

I am interested in parallelization strategies for mixed FE formulation. Appreciate any useful material on this.

Answer (score 0):

You do not like to have two or more different meshes, differently partitioned.  That will make massive communication. Degrees of freedom from multiple fields should be as close as possible to each other in adjacency tree, to make interprocessor communication to a minimum.

You have one mesh, but you have DOFs associated with different entities, for example for H1 space, piece-linear continuous, DOFs are on nodes, whereas DOFs for L2 space, price-linear discontinuous, DOFs are on cells. That is for the simple case, for vectorial spaces, like H-div or H-curl, things are a bit more complicated. Of cores, for example, hierarchical space, you can have DOFs on vertices, edges, faces, and cells.

So you partition cells. Sub-entities, i.e. nodes, edges, faces, on the skin of partition are shared. DOFs on shared entities are typically owned by a partition with a lower rank. On other partitions, DOFs on shared entities are so-called ghost DOFs. You can create a special vector with ghost DOFs; you have such vectors in PETSc.

To partition cells, you need to build a graph; then you can use metis, or parameters to partition it. Itself, you have many strategies on how to partition the graph. You can build a graph as well in a different way. You can do it by the numbering of cells and then make an adjacent matrix, by finding neighbour cells through bridge entity. Bridge entity can be node, edge or face. For classical FEM you would use bridge adjacency entity as a vertex. For H-div - L2 formulation bridge adjacency entity should be facing. Since for H-div space, DOFs are on faces (and volumes). When you are using H-curl space, bridge adjacency entity will be an edge. For discontinuous Petrov-Galerkin, bridge adjacency entity will be on a face, since DOFs are on the skeleton.

Moreover, each cell can have weight, if you heterogenous order of approximation. That is needed for load balancing, to distribute work among processors equally.

In the end, there are many solutions, many strategies.

But why to do it by yourself, I can point you to the FEM code, which does it all for you.

Comment: Thank you @likask! The elements (Bezier elements) I am using are not yet available in any FEM package. (Please correct me if I am wrong about this. ) So, I have to do it myself. I use METIS for mesh partitioning in my CFD/FSI code but there I use pressure stabilisation. So, no issues with book-keeping.
Please point me to the FEM code concerned with the partitioning and DOFs numbering for mixed elements. Thanks!

Comment: You can see parallel mix problem here
http://mofem.eng.gla.ac.uk/mofem/html/mix_transport.html
I can point you to other examples which Bernstein-Bezier base, and other coupled problems. For are another case see the problem which three fields and two-element types
http://mofem.eng.gla.ac.uk/mofem/html/cell_forces_8cpp-example.html
I've developed code, so I am not fully objective.

Comment: Thank you very much for the links! I am going to check these resources right away.